# Inverse of a constant function on an open set

Tags: complex-analysis, inverse, riemann-surfaces

I was working on holomorphic functions and Riemann surfaces, and I was wondering about the inverse of a constant function:

Let $f:U\rightarrow V$ be a holomorphic function between two Riemann surfaces $U$ and $V$. If $f$ is constant, with $f(u_0)=v_0$, what happens with the inverse $f^{-1}:V\rightarrow U$? Is it even defined in $v_0 \in V$? And if it's defined there, is the following true: $f^{-1}(v_0)=U$?

Any help with clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with complex analysis or Riemann surfaces. It's purely to do with sets and functions. Do you know what an inverse function is?

Comment: I have a basic understanding of inverses, but at the time that I asked this question, I just realised that something I had taken for granted in an assignment wouldn't necessarily be true, which made me kind of panic.
I didn't really notice that this hadn't anything to do with complex analysis in specific either, but I see it now when you pointed it out.
After reading up on the subject, after completing the original assignment in a different way, it seems that I jsut got a bit confused over preimages.

Comment: A function $f:U\to V$ has an inverse function $f^{-1}$ if and only if every element of $V$ has one and only one element in its preimage. In particular, if $f$ is a constant function, then that constant is the only element of $V$ with a (nonempty) preimage, and furthermore its preimage is the whole of $U$ (so certainly that constant has more than one element in its preimage usually).